# PHP/MySQL: Can 12 CPU cores make app faster than 6 CPU cores although CPU usage always below 40%?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, innodb

our problem is that MySQL is delaying our app after we reduced the CPU cores, although CPU usage always is and has been below 40%. My question is: Was it really the CPU reduction which triggered MySQL to be slow now? Or should I be looking somewhere else?

More details: My team is running a mobile app with up to a couple of thousand users being online at the same time. They fire up to 100 requests/second to the backend. We are using PHP/MySQL and had 12 CPU cores and 8 GB RAM. The tool phpMyAdmin showed that CPU usage was 15-25% and RAM usage at 1 GB.

Then we reduced CPU cores to 6. CPU usage went up to about 40% max. However, faced with higher load (but not higher load than we had while running 12 cores) MySQL is not able to process all queries immediately and queries are lining up delaying our whole app. This did not happen when we had 12 cores.

I would be grateful for any hints or tips. We are already conducting a full-review of the server(variable) configuration. We are using only InnoDB-tables.

Thanks a lot,
Fman

Comment: MySQL mostly depends on the hard disk and ram it has at its disposal. You've mentioned nothing about that. Also, there's this magic variable called `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. It's default value is 8MB. You want that variable very high, up to 80-90% of your RAM.

Comment: @Martin Barker I know that queries are lining up using "SHOW PROCESSLIST". Yesterday, during peak hours, many queries were waiting 2-20 seconds to be processed. I have no limit on concurrent connections (set to 0). The whole thing runs on Apache 2.2.22, MySQL Version 5.5.37 and PHP 5.4.30.

Comment: Can MySQL do side by side Queries? with innoDB?

Comment: What is your MySQL / InnoDB Version as InnoDB on Linux can only do async queries as of version 1.1 (MySQL 5.5) so if your 5.4 there queued.

Comment: @N.B. Indeed this is the first step that we will do although it is unclear to which value to set? Currently we have set innodb_buffer_pool_size at 128 MB. Now, I have 2 conflicting pieces of information: 1) Increase to 80% of total RAM. 2) At most 1024 MiB because log file size is recommended to be 25% of it but not bigger than 256 MiB. Any tips whether 2) is important?

Comment: @MartinBarker It's Apache 2.2.22, MySQL Version 5.5.37 and PHP 5.4.30

Comment: When in doubt - best check what each thing does. `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is a number that says how much RAM MySQL is allowed to allocate for whatever purpose. Usually, MySQL keeps the working data set there. It means it's going to pull the data from RAM rather than HDD. With 128MB you can't do much. You want your **entire** data set to fit into RAM. It's not a problem to crunch the data, the problem is getting data fast enough to the CPU. Transferring it from HDD to CPU is, well, slow :)

Comment: As for log files, [Percona guys](http://www.percona.com/blog/2006/07/03/choosing-proper-innodb_log_file_size/) explains it really well so I don't think I've much to say about it.

Comment: @N.B yeah reading though south bridge for every request can get bad

Comment: Why are you using InnoDB are you using Transactions? if not thats alot of overhead for no reason MyISAM is quicker for none transaction queries it might also be worth looking at MariaDB it's MySQL Supporting (drop in replacement) with a lot more supporting Storage Engines and optimizations so one of them might be better, but also you can mix InnoDB and MyISAM to get the best performance

Comment: @N.B. I want to endlessly thank you for the link to the Percona guys. There I found 3 extremely helpful links (http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/20/innodb-performance-optimization-basics-updated/,
http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/, https://tools.percona.com/wizard/server).
They are invaluable (as it seems to me) in improving my performance in the next couple of days.

Comment: @FMan - you're welcome, and yes - they have excellent articles about tuning and various other things. Also, since we're already here, here's another thing you might consider and that just might solve your problems just like that - [a drop-in ACID compliant engine for MySQL with excellent performance and compression rate](http://www.tokutek.com/tokudb-for-mysql/). As for the comment about using MyISAM - it really isn't faster than InnoDB if you are able to utilize InnoDB to its full potential. You should more or less never need MyISAM.

Comment: I have inconsequential question. Do you use cache?

Comment: @Kristiyan I use query_cache if this is what you mean (query cache size 32 MiB) if that is what you mean? could that explain the phenomenon I saw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like your MySQL is probably reaching it's I/O limits. We did a stress test on our DB server and something that's critical to understanding DB choke points is that when you add or change records, you have to do a disk write (`SELECT` can be cached). So when we were just reading our website it handled quite a load, but when we simulated a checkout (multiple records created) it bogged down very quickly.

Back then, we didn't have any options. SSDs were too expensive to provision vs magnetic (and our choke number was way beyond anything we've ever really hit). Best we could do was RAID 10. But, thanks to clouds, you can now easily (and cheaply) have a fairly powerful DB server that will handle the I/O loads much better (especially with SSD prices dropping rapidly). You'll note that Amazon sells even their middle instances on the [Provisioned IOPS feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#USER_PIOPS)

> For any production application that requires fast and consistent I/O performance, we recommend Provisioned IOPS (input/output operations per second) storage. Provisioned IOPS storage is a storage type that delivers fast, predictable, and consistent throughput performance. When you create a DB instance, you specify an IOPS rate and storage space allocation. Amazon RDS provisions that IOPS rate and storage for the lifetime of the DB instance or until you change it. Provisioned IOPS storage is optimized for I/O intensive, online transaction processing (OLTP) workloads that have consistent performance requirements.

It sounds very much like you probably have a simple setup (and maybe even host your DB on the same server). AWS isn't the only game in town but you might want to consider moving to some sort of cloud, or at least step up to something that can handle the higher I/O demands you're putting on your server. Forget the number of cores. If your HDD is choking you could be running 72 cores and not have any difference whatsoever.

One other tip: Check out [MySQL Tuner](http://mysqltuner.com/). When you run it, it checks your database stats (the longer it's been running, the better) and can recommend lots of helpful tweaks that can also improve performance.