# mysql performance issues on large tables with insert

Tags: php, mysql

We have a dedicated server with 8GB of RAM and PHP5.3 with MySQL 5.1

There are about 500 concurrent connections at maximum and each connection performs 1-2 SELECT queries on the smaller tables with the user data and then an INSERT in the big table `transactions`. The select queries don't take much and we added monitoring between each query to see the response time of each query and there were never problems.

We added tracking to our code and sometimes it results that some simple INSERT queries take 14-15 seconds. This query listed below sometimes takes 14 seconds, sometimes 6 seconds, sometimes 0.2 seconds or less. What could be the issue?

PHP code that sometimes returns these huge delays:

```
$starT = microtime(true);
echo '&timestampTS_02='.(microtime(true) - $startT);
mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],"INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`,`data`) VALUES('id','some_data')") or die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['con']));
echo '&timestampTS_03='.(microtime(true) - $startT);
```

The `transactions` table has around 2 million entries so far.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: MyISAM is not the best storage option for this, at least test **InnoDB**

Comment: What is the value of concurrent_insert?

Comment: @Dagon This table is usually InnoDB because we have more inserts and very few SELECT data. But the problems were since it was InnoDB so we switched to MyISAM to see if it behaves better. We did not monitor each query when the table was InnoDB. Do you think that it would behave better as InnoDB once we find the issue? Because it's clear that it is not from the DB storage type.

Comment: @Buddy Can I find that using phpMyAdmin or by executing any query? Or how can I get the value of "concurrent_insert"?

Comment: @NVG - `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'concurrent%';`

Comment: Like @Dagon hinted already, `InnoDB` behaves better than `MyISAM`. Since you're able to swap between engines, try `TokuDB` as well, it should behave much better. Also, what's the hard drive you're using (mechanical or SSD) and what's the MySQL configuration for your server? It's difficult to determine if you're I/O bound or not, and by the looks of it - it would appear you are. In I/O bound cases, it's the best that you somehow queue writes and flush a few tens or hundreds of them in a single I/O.

Comment: Which MYSQL storage engine would be best for very many UPDATE and INSERT queries and no SELECT queries?

Comment: @Buddy concurrent_insert has value 1

Comment: 1. Why are you using MySQL 5.1 ???? How old is that. 5.3 is the absolute minimum you should be using anyway.

Comment: @DavidSoussan It came like that with the Linux distribution. You think that the performance difference is big enough between 5.1 and 5.5?
5.1.73 is the version used and it dates from (2013-12-03)

Comment: 5.1 was rubbish. It had all sorts of problems and lacked many features. The earliest version you should use is 5.5 which included many performance improvements.

Comment: Also, 5.1 dates from 2010 not 2013. Just because your host is too lazy to upgrade their standard build does not mean they got it right. We had that with rackspace managed server and they seemed surprised when I asked why it was not 5.5/5.6. Just the security enhancements made it a no-brainer let alone the improved performance especialy with InnoDB

Comment: Are you also performing read queries on the transactions table? Considering this is a table with only two fields, what type of queries are you running? Does 'data' contain structured information, like xml or json?

Comment: Please check these two link:- http://doc.ctrlaltdel.ch/database/mysql/manual_Performance.html. http://www.percona.com/blog/2006/06/09/why-mysql-could-be-slow-with-large-tables/. May be you can get help from these links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table might be locked for another process. This can be an hardware problem (slow or end-life hard drive), software or conjectural (slow server in shared system).

You could watch what is locking the insert with a `show processlist`

Comment: -1 for suggesting a deprecated feature: "As of MySQL 5.6.6, INSERT DELAYED is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release."

Comment: Thanks for noticing this, i removed this line as it wasn't the first main point of my answer

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think this is the issue. I saw a list of several processes when running the `show processlist` query. Do you think that switching to InnoDB will remove this issue?

Comment: Let's see that `PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: You have to read your processlist in order to find the one that is executing and locking the others. It's very hard to say that switching to innodb will change anything without knowing which process it is. But you can give it a try if it works. But assuming it could be hardware, the fact that you won't see the bug, will not mean that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

InnoDB.  (Because some of the things below need it.)

Batch inserts.  `Either by INSERT ... VALUES (1,2,3), (4,5,6), ...` or with `LOAD DATA`.  (10x performance boost when you insert 100 rows at once.)  If you cannot 'batch', then see the 'staging table' suggestion, below.

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2  (not the default of 1)  (This may be why your tests failed to show good performance.)

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 70% of available RAM.  (About 5000M in your 8GB machine).

Upgrade from 5.1.  (But this won't solve the problem alone.)

If possible, decrease the number of indexes on `transactions`.

For really high rate of ingestion, ping-pong two "staging tables" as discussed in [High Speed Ingestion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).

Comment: a)Each table from our database has only primary keys, that means 1 index.
b)Isn't the buffer pool too much ... 70% of RAM? RIight now it is around 15%.
c)With each user request, one INSERT query is made. So are you suggesting to combine multiple INSERT queries from different connections in a batch and run them all at once when they reach 100 rows for example?

Comment: Do you make up the `id`s?  It does not look like they are `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  If each connection is doing a single insert, it does not make sense to batch them -- unless you need hundreds of rows inserted per second.  Then it would get tricky to "batch" them.

Comment: 14 seconds for MyISAM is possible due to "table locking".  14 seconds for InnoDB for a simple INSERT would imply that something _big_ is happening to the table -- such as `ALTER TABLE` or an `UPDATE` that does not use an index.  Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see what is running when a slow INSERT occurs.

Comment: What value do you use for autocommit?  Do you do `BEGIN...COMMIT`?

Comment: It might also be worth to check if key packing is enabled. Key packing is basically string truncating to speed up read speeds, but it slows down write speeds.

Comment: @RickJames ids are autoincremented, but I probably deleted that from the example. We do not use any commits. I think table locking caused all this as well.

Comment: Now you have me worried.  If you "simplified" the queries and schema for the question, you may have removed the thing that is causing the problem !

Answer (score 4):

In any database (regardless of engine) [the highest cost is always in writing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869188/php-mysql-can-12-cpu-cores-make-app-faster-than-6-cpu-cores-although-cpu-usage/26922730#26922730) because you add the overhead of a mandatory disc operation (with enough RAM, a MySQL server can cache tables and queries well enough to avoid high I/O for `SELECT`). MyISAM (with table locking) is probably not helping vs InnoDB (with row locking) but you don't necessarily have to switch storage engines.

One major tip on multiple inserts is to use a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). You set the query up once, then change the parameters and execute it once per row. As specified in the [MySQL Manual for speed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html) (emphasis mine)

> The time required for inserting a row is determined by the following factors, where the numbers indicate approximate proportions:
>   Connecting: (3)
>   **Sending query to server: (2)**
>   **Parsing query: (2)**
>   Inserting row: (1 × size of row)
>   Inserting indexes: (1 × number of indexes)
>   Closing: (1)

Because prepared statements are sent and parsed only once (bolded above), it saves quite a bit of overhead, as well as securing your data inserts.

Another option would be to enable [concurrent inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/concurrent-inserts.html). This is only an option if you don't delete data from that table.

The last one may not be terrible feasible for you but should be something to consider if this is a major pain point for your business. Modern cloud computing has drastically reduced the cost of higher I/O options (RAID, SSD, etc). You might want to switch to a cloud service (AWS, Azure, etc) that has a high I/O option. You can throw as much RAM as you want at your database but if your storage is slow this will only drag the rest of your database down with it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. We will increase the number of concurrent inserts, we will increase the buffer size and will do some tests with MyISAM vs InnoDB to see which delivers the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the `transactions` table is referenced as the holder of a foreign key.

Then run `show triggers` and check if any trigger is set to run if something changes in `transactions` or any of the referencing tables.

Then tweak any triggers found.

If this doesn't help, go back to the tracking you added to your code, and add the following: just before running the query, check which queries were already running at that moment and log that as well. It could be you will find some slow query already running that is locking your table.

Comment: At this moment there are no triggers on any of our tables. How can I check which queries are already running at that moment? It could be that MyISAM locked the table from a slower connection and that is some other queries get slower? I have been receiving many suggestions to switch ti InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `InnoDB` engine instead of `MyISAM` 
you can config your mysql configuration via this site :
[www.percona.com](http://www.percona.com)

Note : [innodb-buffer-pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) is very important in your configuration

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have changed to InnoDB, but the performance did not change.

Comment: Because InnoDB need to configuration , what is the your my.cnf data?Please post it, you can find in /etc/my.cnf

Comment: While busy with percona, install cacti and the percona-mysql plugin for cacti. That will give lots of insight in your mysql database and what you can tweak.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli on large data, it have multiple insert statement feature.

And is preferable in dedicated servers.

See the link - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp

Regards

Comment: So instead of connecting to the mysql server 2 times for 2 INSERT queries, I connect just once and I insert both of them, this way probably reducing the memory and response time to half, when compared to 2 requests being sent as separate.

Comment: Yes, most web hosting providers are switching to mysqli, because of its performance and features. And you don't have to change your db settings like other people are saying. You must use it.

Comment: If required then you have to use multiple insert, you can use while loop to create multiple insert query. And then execute it.